# How to remove default date selection of datepicker from Angular Material?

Tags: angular, datepicker, calendar, angular-material, angular-material2

Okay, I do not know if this is possible, but the angular material `datepicker` selects the date of the day by default.
I would like no `datepicker` dates to be selected by default.

**EDIT:** This is only visual, no date is selected when closing but I would like the date of the day not to be visible as on the gif.

Here is the `datepicker` of angular material: [Stackblitz HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/remove-default-date-selection-from-datepicker)

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In your stackblitz the datepicker is empty by default on page load.The date is visible only after I select a date.

Comment: Yes, I am looking to remove the visual of today's day

Comment: What do you mean by remove the visual of today's day. Can you elaborate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been trying to help since a long time. I found a work around. Not a perfect solution

You can include the following css

```
::ng-deep .mat-calendar-body-today {
  border: none !important;
}
```

The above css is to remove the border of the current date.

I was trying to remove the highlighted part but could not.

I shared to give a insight on what can be done.

Please look at the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/remove-default-date-selection-from-datepicker-tfnmnh) here

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I finally used the following CSS class:`.mat-calendar-body-today {
    border-color: transparent!important;
    background-color: transparent!important;
}`

Comment: **EDIT Answer:** `.mat-calendar-body-today:not(.mat-calendar-body-selected) {
  border-color: transparent!important;
  background-color: transparent!important;
}`

Answer (score 0):

It's not selecting it. It shows you the current day. I don't think you can disable that. If you get out of the datepicker, no date will be chosen.

Comment: I know that the `datepicker` has no default date selected, I am looking to remove today's visual from the `datepicker`.

Comment: I don't think its possible to do that.